# Constrained zero diagonal low rank approximation of a matrix with zero diagonal

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Suppose that you have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that is symmetric and has zero diagonal, such as for example
$$
A=\pmatrix{
0 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0},
$$
and you want to represent it by a low rank approximation **but** respecting the symmetry and the zero diagonal in the output of that approximation. Like doing the eigenvalue decomposition by the spectral theorem
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_iv_i^T
$$
and then truncate this sum to get an approximation for $k\leq n$ (assuming $|\lambda_1|\geq\ldots\geq|\lambda_n|$). But if you do this for $A$ of course you get something like (with two eigenvalues)
$$
A=\pmatrix{
0 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
2 & 0.5 & 0.5
},$$
which is not in the spirit of what I want.

**Question**: Is there a standard procedure/method for dimension reduction respecting these constraints?

**EDIT 1**: I realized that since you need to have a zero diagonal output as an approximation matrix, this implies full rank except if some of the entries are zero. So I guess the answer is in choosing which entries are set to zero and how the others are reweighted.

Thanks!