# constrained rank approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, svd, constraints

I'm trying to solve a problem similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282203/constrained-zero-diagonal-low-rank-approximation-of-a-matrix-with-zero-diagonal). Instead of requiring the diagonals to be 0, I'd like to require columns of the low rank approximation to decrease in value while going down the rows.

I'm not exactly sure where to begin, especially as the referenced stack exchange post has no replies. I've read [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379502005050/1-s2.0-S0024379502005050-main.pdf?_tid=930a8a1d-e247-4681-859d-2beee25ac467&acdnat=1544661130_d92ddf4c786b2d530a546324508006ac) which seems relevant, but I've been unable to translate it to my example (which seems comparatively simple).

**Edit with more detail:**

I'd like to minimize $||A-\hat A||$ where $A$ is my original data of full rank, $\hat A$ is a rank k matrix, and $||.||$ is the Frobenius norm. I'd like to add the constraint that columns decrease in value as you go down rows.

I've been able to achieve this by a truncated singular value decomposition followed by iterating a constrained least-squares eq. on every column, but I'd like to solve this as one problem. The constrained l.s. problem I've been using is as follows: $min||x-d||$ such that $Cx \le 0$ where d is a vector of data, x is the modeled data, and C is a matrix that finds the difference along x when multiplied.

$$
C=\pmatrix{
-1 & 1 &  & &\\
 & -1 & 1 & &\\
 &  & & ... &\\
 & &  & -1 & 1},
$$

Comment: No, that is not an assumption of mine. Thanks for your suggestions, I'll edit my post to try and make it more explicit.

Comment: It's a novel problem to me.  How big are the matrices $A$ that you want to approximate?  Will the columns of $A$ be in descending order, or is this only a feature of the approximating $\hat A$?  Is it allowed to have negative entries?

Comment: The largest $A$ I have is about 3000x100, but this could be downsampled if that proves to be too large. Most are around 300x200 or smaller. The descending property is not true in $A$, only the approximation. In a physical sense, $\hat A$ should never be negative as it represents river surface elevations, but the values in $A$ should also never be negative.

Comment: $k$ will be quite small, somewhere between 2 and 5. If it makes it easier to predetermine $k$ as 2, that is fine as well.

Comment: I set myself the following "toy" version of your problem, with $A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 9 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 & 7 \\ 8 & 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$, to find the best approximating matrix $A'$ with columns in descending order.  I get $A' = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 9 & 5 \\ 5 & 5 & 5 \\ 5 & 1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$, which happens to have rank $2$.  Does it match your calculations?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on holiday. Yes, that does match what I get exactly.

Comment: I've taken a look at the 2003 paper you linked by Chu, Funderlic, and Plemmons, "Structured low rank approximation".  I am acquainted with one of the authors, and I'd be happy to email them to ask if more recent or more relevant references are known to them, giving a brief account of your application.

Comment: Plots of an $A$ and $\hat{A}$ would be nice

Comment: Here is a fairly recent (revised March 2018) literature reference: [Low-rank Optimization with Convex Constraints](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01793).

Answer (score 1):

Minimize $\sum_{ij} |A_{ij} - X_{ij}| $ with the constraints $X_{ij} \ge X_{i+1,j}$
with linear programming.
This is different from minimizing the usual sum-of-squares, but may be adequate.

(There are programs and preprocessors that ease the task of expanding a few lines like the above
to a large flat LP.
[Julia JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl)
can run various LP solvers, opensource, academic opensource, commercial; I gather these have very different runtimes,
very problem-dependent.
JuMP looks nice, but today (January 2019) work-in-progress.
See also
[questions/tagged/julia-jump+or+linear-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-jump+or+linear-programming)
on SO.)